# Why the font appear with bad quality?

Tags: java, android

I'm using bitmap font to show text, but the text appear with very bad quality... How I can to sharp the text?
I tried to change fonts, but nothing.

Comment: please show relevant code and screenshots.....

Answer (score 3):

If you really have a bitmap font, that is the reason. Suppose, your characters have a height of 20 pixels and you render them with a height of e.g. 1cm. On a Nexus 5 (which has a resolution of 1920 x 1080 pixels), 1 cm estimates (very roughly) 150 pixels. Thus, Android **scapes up** your bitmap from 20 pixels to 150 pixels, which results in the bad quality.

You will have to switch to a vector based font to achieve good quality.

Comment: If you insist on bitmap fonts, you could just try to use a REALLY big font, so that no or not much up-scaling is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap fonts just like other bitmaps should have multiple copies for different densities.